# How to eliminate column with same name using self join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

In this stored procedure, I have to use

```
SELECT * 
FROM @policyData a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ##Temp b ON b.qguid = a.quoteguid
LEFT OUTER JOIN ##Temp c ON c.qguid = a.quoteguid2;
```

And because of that I have two columns with the same name "QuoteGuid".

Then when I try to add this query in SSRS, I get an error, because I have 2 columns with the same name.

I am not the author of this stored procedure, so I cannot understand is any chance to eliminate or rename column name that causing this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_Catalytic_WindEQRenewalExtract
    @pos INT,
    @len INT,
    @value varchar(8000),
    @PriorDays INT,
    @PastDays INT,
    @LineName varchar(50)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT @LineName ='wind'
    SELECT @PriorDays= -15
    SELECT @PastDays = 55

    DECLARE @policyData TABLE
            (
                NamedInsured varchar(1000),
                displaystatus varchar(100),
                quoteguid uniqueidentifier,
                quoteid int,
                controlno int,
                ExpirationDate datetime, 
                MonthName nvarchar(25),
                ExpiringPremium money,
                Underwriter varchar(250),
                linename varchar(25),
                RenewalSubmissionRecieved varchar(5),
                QuotedPremium money,
                quoteguid2 uniqueidentifier,
                controlno2 int,
                displaystatus2 varchar(50),
                quotestatuscomment varchar(2500),
                quotestatusreasoncomment varchar(2500),
                BoundPremium money,
                Underwriter2 varchar(500)
            )

INSERT INTO @policyData
EXEC ('Catalytic_sp_FetchRenewalPolicy ' + @PriorDays + ',' + @PastDays + ', ' + @LineName + '')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols =     STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.locationCode) 
     FROM Catalytic_vw_LocationCodeByLine c WHERE c.linename =@LineName order by c.CompanyName, c.LocationCode
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
                           DROP TABLE ##Temp; 



set @query =       

            'select *  into ##Temp
            from 

            (SELECT  QUOTEGUID as qguid, ' + @cols + ' from   
                    (
                        select QuoteGUID, LocationCode, LineName,LineGUID
                        --from Catalytic_vw_PolicyLocationCode where quoteguid=''99D60178-C33B-4A3F-9EA7-0001EF31626A''
                                 from Catalytic_vw_PolicyLocationCode 
                   )  x
                    pivot 
                    (
                         max(locationCode)
                        for locationCode in (' + @cols + ')
                    )p)x'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;

set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @cols, @pos+1)>0
BEGIN
    set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @cols, @pos+1) - @pos
    set @value = SUBSTRING(@cols, @pos, @len)

   -- PRINT @value
    set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @cols, @pos+@len) +1

    declare @sql nvarchar (1000);
set @sql = N'update ##Temp set ' + @value + '= ''X'' where  len(' + @value + ') > 0 ' ;
exec sp_executesql @sql;


END

SELECT * 
 FROM
              @policyData a
              LEFT OUTER  JOIN ##Temp b on b.qguid = a.quoteguid
              /*Because I am using another LEFT JOIN here, I have two columns namem "qguid"*/
              LEFT OUTER  JOIN ##Temp c on c.qguid = a.quoteguid2;
DROP TABLE ##Temp;
```

[image]

Comment: Only select columns relevant to your query (name the columns instead of using *) OR if (for whatever reason) you need all columns, give the columns a distinct name (e.g. `select qguid1 = a.qguid, qguid2 = b.qguid, qguid3 = c.qguid...`). In either case, you want to select specific columns instead of using *.

Comment: Considering the fact that the column list in the `##Temp` table is seemingly dynamic, you may have a difficult task here. Do you need columns from both the `b` and `c` `##Temp` aliases?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s  Thank you very much, I forgot about that

Comment: R.Richards - I think you do understand my problem. Yes, i need columns from both ##Temp `b` and `c`. But columns are dynamic. Any idea how to solve this problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just change where you are trying to make another left join in the last and explicitly mention all column name.

```
SELECT a.* ,b.*,c.qguid as qguid1
 FROM
              @policyData a
              LEFT OUTER  JOIN ##Temp b on b.qguid = a.quoteguid
              /*Because I am using another LEFT JOIN here, I have two columns namem "qguid"*/
              LEFT OUTER  JOIN ##Temp c on c.qguid = a.quoteguid2;

Another way,

declare @CurDate datetime=getdate()
Declare @CurDate1 varchar(8)


select @CurDate1= replace(convert(varchar(8), @CurDate, 112), ':','') 
select @CurDate1

SET @cols =     STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.locationCode) +@CurDate1
     FROM Catalytic_vw_LocationCodeByLine c WHERE c.linename =@LineName order by c.CompanyName, c.LocationCode
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: I like the idea, but the problem is I also need the rest of the columns from `c`, and those columns are dynamic, so I cant say `c.RHS, c.RIC`  etc
You know what I mean?
Thanks

Comment: now check my alternative way,though i hv not fully understood.because i think you can do update operation without while loop etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you need to use an existing stored procedure to get data for an SSRS report and you cannot modify the procedure. The problem is the stored procedure returns two columns with the same name and SSRS will not accept that in a dataset.

To get around that call the stored procedure and store its results in a temp table with different column names. Then output the temp table contents. This gives you fill control over the name of the columns. See example below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        1 AS 'Test1',
        2 AS 'Test2',
        3 AS 'Test3',
        3 AS 'Test3'
END

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Test1 int,
    Test2 int,
    Test3 int,
    Test4 int
)

INSERT INTO #Test
EXEC dbo.sp_Test

SELECT * FROM #Test

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: you understating it correctly. The problem is that output of the procedure is dynamic, so one day it can be certain columns, the other day it could be different number of columns. So I am unable to create #TempTable with static columns.
And I do have a right to modify a stored procedure, but the problem is I didnt come up with idea how to do that yet.